# How to run mutt via ssh without going through an interactive shell

Tags: ssh, terminal, mutt, ncurses

Mutt depends on curses according to this [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4409808#4409808), my discussion with Michael:

> @hhh: ssh hhh@server.com mutt <--- what is wrong here? trying to run mutt there...
>   @MichaelMrozek: mutt uses curses, which depends on a lot of terminal manipulation; I
>   imagine it doesn't like being run within ssh like that

The manual has the entry:

```
ssh [user@]hostname --
[command]
```

How can I run `mutt` running locally from outside the server without needing to `ssh` to it and run `mutt` directly?

Comment: Tried `ssh -t`?

Comment: @jw013 That's rather handy. That's probably the right answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From `man 1 ssh`

```
-t  Force pseudo-tty allocation. This can be used to execute arbitrary
    screen-based programs on a remote machine, which can be very useful,
    e.g. when implementing menu services.  Multiple -t options force tty 
    allocation, even if ssh has no local tty.
```

Now `mutt` has a tty to display it's menus on. (You would use `-tt` if connecting to `mutt` remotely via a script from `cron`, for example.)

`ssh -t hhh@server.com mutt`

Comment: @jw013 beat me to it. Again.

Comment: Nice catch, thanks, this can probably become quite useful.

Comment: Suppose now that I would like to save an attachement to my local machine from which I have done the SSH -connection, how would you do that? I noticed that it did it to the hhh@server.com -location. Some good ideas?

Comment: Hmmm, perhaps install the `fuse-sshfs` package and mount a directory from your local machine onto the system remotely running `mutt`.

Comment: @hhh You realize running `ssh server.com command` runs the command on the remote machine, right? Your question and the comment here make it sound like you think it's somehow running locally

Comment: @MichaelMrozek hopefully not, I was already thinking the next puzzle! Hope to solve that as well! Puzzles are interesting -- the desire for knowledge is never ending!

Comment: @uther: what is the difference between fuse-sshfs and sshfs? I have used sshfs many times, hey do you mean something like `sshfs hhh@server.com newDir`, `cd newDir` (on $HOME) and then just `mutt`, well here some path problems. Some example? If I can understand you right, your idea was to mount the default files with the server-side -files or?

Comment: Basically just find a way to mount a local directory onto the remote server that you are executing `mutt` from. You can use `sshfs`, `cifs`, `nfs` or whatever you prefer. The whole point would be to have a directory mounted from your local host onto the remote server so that you can save attachments from `mutt` directly into the directory, effectively saving it locally.