# How do I execute a remote shell script over SSH and be prompted for passwords by commands that require it in that script?

Tags: bash, shell, ssh, shell-script

I want to do something like this

```
ssh user@remote-domain.com ./remote_script.sh
```

Contents of remote_script.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
hg pull
```

This example is much simpler than what I am actually doing. I know I can pass shell commands directly over ssh, but assume I want to run a remote script. Also I know Mercurial has hooks, but ignore that as well, I am only using Mercurial as an example here for brevity.

This is what I expect to happen, a password prompt for the user:

```
user@repository-domain.com password:
```

This is the output:

```
ssh user@remote-domain.com ./remote_script.sh
remote: Permission denied, please try again.
remote: Permission denied, please try again.
remote: Permission denied (publickey,password).
abort: no suitable response from remote hg!
```

The remote shell session seems to be feeding something to the password input prompts and failing after 3 automated tries. I would really like the prompt to reach my local shell session. Perhaps that isn't possible.

I don't want to give the remote server key authentication to the repository, I'd prefer the user be prompted each time. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to run mutt via ssh without going through an interactive shell](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/37643/how-to-run-mutt-via-ssh-without-going-through-an-interactive-shell)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's hard to figure out what exactly is going on from this post.  Is the password prompt being printed by the hg command (I'm not familiar with hg)?

I recommend you try adding the `-t` option to ssh:

```
ssh -t user@remote-domain.com ./remote_script.sh
```

Comment: The `-t` option seems to do what I want. Thank you.