# connect to a remote server through ssh

Tags: linux, shell-script

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I execute a remote shell script over SSH and be prompted for passwords by commands that require it in that script?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/37911/how-do-i-execute-a-remote-shell-script-over-ssh-and-be-prompted-for-passwords-by)

I want to connect to a remote server through ssh. i have to also provide password within that script. after connecting to the remote server i want to run the serverstartup script. please provide sample example.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can write a script using expect tool.

In Redhat, expect package comes by default. But in Ubuntu you need to install it separately.

You can check this by using commands:

`$ rpm -qa | grep expect` for Redhat

`$ dpkg -l expect` for Ubuntu

The following script will do your work:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

spawn ssh username@hostname
expect "username@hostname's password: "
send "password\r"
interact
exec <path_of_init_script>
```

where `username` is the actual username by which you are logging in,
      `hostname` may be hostname or ip address, and password is the actual password.

This way you can log into the box and run the script.